# Get Object has no method 'executeDbCommand'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> I am using mongodb 3.0.2 with mongoose 4.0 in nodejs

- While i upgrade mongoose 2.3 to 4.0 it started to throw error for
  'executeDbCommand', it looks like this is deprecated in mongoose 4.0,
  anyone has an idea for replacement of this command ?

I tried to dig into the mongoose but cant find it, Please help me if anyone knows !!

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose uses a [native driver](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-mongo) in itself prototype, and api docs says that native drive has a [command method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#command). The code will be:

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database');
db.command('sample command');
```